# FW/1 How to set up multiple layouts

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, fw1

I want to have two different layouts for my site. default.cfm site wide layout, and in the admin section admin.cfm for the layout. Creating admin.cfm in /layouts and navigating to admin.index does show the admin template, but the default.cfm sitewide template is also displaying. How do you set these up so only one is showing that needs to be showing?

Looking at the FW/1 docs [link](https://framework-one.github.io/documentation/4.3/developing-applications/#views-and-layouts-in-more-depth) it mentions setlayout() but when I tried to use that i get the error "Problem with metadata for admin (controllers.admin) because: Unable to getComponentMetadata(controllers.admin) because: No matching function [SETLAYOUT] found, near line 2 in C:\Sites\actmeio_fw2\controllers\admin.cfc"

```
component accessors="true" persistent="true" {
setLayout('admin');

public any function index(event, rc, prc) {
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the basic structure of your controller file and `setlayout()` function call you tried.

Comment: OK, so the function is there in source control: https://github.com/framework-one/fw1/blob/7508da93998c427f51bcb00116d5cb521c73e795/framework/one.cfc#L1318. "when I tried to use that it says that function doesn't exist"... did you actually investigate this? Look for the function? What docs were you reading? IE: give us the link and show us the relevant bit. What's your code? We can't guess all this stuff, you need to help us to help you a bit here, please.

Comment: I updated my OP with more info. Curious to see what I am doing wrong, but the answer below fixes my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your `admin.cfm` layout template, try adding

```
<cfscript>
disableLayout();
</cfscript>
```

This should prevent the `default.cfm` outer layout being applied. For more details see https://framework-one.github.io/documentation/4.3/developing-applications/#views-and-layouts-in-more-depth